# Resolve observable properties with http calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

Im trying to write an API interface for the public https://pokeapi.co/
When trying to query for a Pokémon, the API doesn't return the entire model, it returns url references to children instead.

(trying to query https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/name)

instead of the expected

```
Pokemon { 
  id,
  name,
  types[ (Actual model)
    {
      id,
      name,
      otherProperties...
    }
  ]
}
```

i get

```
Pokemon { 
  id,
  name,
  types[ (Reference to the actual model)
    {
      name,
      url
    }
  ]
}
```

How do i make a method findPokemonByName(string: name) which returns the root pokemon and maps the types as nested http requests to https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/name using HttpClient and rxjs?

Comment: You need to understand how Observables work, specifically in the context of http calls. [This article may be of interest](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Comment: Please paste some code you've tried to write

Comment: do you want to actually make all of the requests or just build the requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the preview for the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PokemonService {
  private baseAPIUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

   }

   public getPokemonByName(name: string) {
     return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseAPIUrl}pokemon/${name}`)
     .pipe(
       switchMap((pokemon: any) => {
         return forkJoin({
           types: forkJoin(this.generateRequestsForTypes(pokemon.types))
         })
       }, (pokemon, result) => {
         pokemon.types = result.types;
         return pokemon;
       }),
     )
   }

  private getPokemonTypeByUrl(url: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get(url);
  }

  private generateRequestsForTypes(types: any[]) {
    return types.map((type) => this.getPokemonTypeByUrl(type.type.url))
  }
}
```

Of course you have to add the types but I think it could be a good start.

Be careful of the number of requests because every nested property can be a request.

Use result selector function (the last argument for the switchMap operator in the example above).

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjjuac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: the double forkJoin seems not needed here

Comment: I used it to potentially add more properties in the first forkJoin object argument.